# How do I auto-deploy a webserver with Corda nodes that's not the default webserver (e.g. a Spring webserver)?

Tags: corda

When using the default Corda node webserver, running the Gradle `deployNodes` task automatically creates a webserver JAR for each node.

How can I implement similar behaviour for my own webserver implementation (e.g. a Spring webserver)?

Answer (score 0):

Corda webserver is deprecated.

Please take look at our examples on how to write a springboot server that talks to the node: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Basic/spring-webserver